# Clearing Contents of a File in C++ knowing only the FILE *

Tags: c++, c, file

Is it possible to clear the contents (ie. set EOF to the beginning/reset the file) in C++ knowing just the FILE*? I'm writing to a temp file with wb+ access and wish to sometimes clear it and truncate it without adding the calls to fclose and fopen. I dont think it's possible... but if not, why not?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Off-topic: Why are you using `FILE*` in C++? Streams are safer and easier.

Comment: I'm actually adding to someone else's code, and dont want to refactor all of it with streams.

Comment: @GMan: So, assuming you get open fstream instance, how are you going to do this with streams?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It will depend on your platform.  The POSIX standard provides [`ftruncate()`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/ftruncate.html), which requires a file descriptor, not a `FILE` pointer, but it also provides [`fileno()`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fileno.html) to get the file descriptor from the `FILE` pointer.

The analogous facilities will be available in [Windows](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754234.aspx) environments - but under different names.

Comment: (Additionally, `ftruncate` requires the file to be open for writing.)

Comment: @stakx: Since the file is open 'wb+', that is not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this can be done using just the `FILE*`. You can always write null data through the end of the file but that won't truncate it.

Alternately if you have access to the filename (I can't tell from the question) you could use `freopen` which hides the close/open/truncate into a single function call.

Comment: @Cenoc: "thought it was odd that they decided to give you power to expand, but not to shorten" - I recollect that the rationale for this is that there were (are?) systems that didn't have the capability to shorten files.  Seems like there could have been a better alternative (return an error on those systems?), but then again, it might not even be true.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <cstdio>

freopen(null, "w", filePtr);
```

see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/freopen/ for more. espacialy the description for the parameter filename.